# Sirius - Create graphical interface to xtext template language

Tags: dsl, xtext, xtend, eclipse-sirius

in my project we use a Xtext template language to create some documents.
Similar to whats written here:
https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/207_template.html

So basically a template starts with a « and ends with a »
In between we call xtend functions which define what will be visible in the output html document.

We would like to add a graphical editor to the already existing textual one.
I saw that Sirius can interact with Xtext and found the examples quite interesting. 
What I could not figure out was how to tell Sirius to use my already existing xtend functions.

My question is: Is there a way to create a graphical interface for a xtedt template language with sirius or am i running in a dead end?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This seems doable, however it is not clear what you mean by "how to tell Sirius to use my already existing xtend functions". Maybe you could start by providing an example of what your templates look like, and the kind of representation you expect to have.

If I refer to the Xtext example you link, an Xtend function call in your template is an XBlockExpression. You would thus need to specify in Sirius an adequate representation for this metaclass.

Links that may help can be found here: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1090448/